# Ubuntu, updated boost from 1.46 to 1.52, linker asks for 1.46

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, compile, gcc

I was having some trouble compiling with a piece of software using boost (wt, http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). I knew (from testing with another machine) that updating from 1.46 would solve my problem. I removed the old boost libraries with apt. I then downloaded and built 1.52 from source. It completed with all targets built.

Now during compilation the linker returns the following:

```
g++ entry.cpp  -std=c++11 -lwt -lwtfcgi -lboost_signals -lboost_system -lwtdbo -lwtdbosqlite3
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_signals.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_date_time.so.1.46.1, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

After compiling boost 1.52 I recompiled Wt from source. I have verified on another machine wt is able to use boost 1.52. I suspect this is simply some sort of configuration problem, but Google has not been forthcoming with assistance!

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Try running `ldconfig`.

Comment: I did come across that suggestion in my searches, unfortunately I still get the same result when compiling.